# Java add jscrollpane not work

Tags: java

I would like to add a JScrollpane into an existing Jpanel, I created a for loop for adding some buttons, but are not displayed. This is the code, but nothing is displayed inside the Jpanel

```
 public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {
     public Main() {
            initComponents();
//EXISTING JPANEL
        gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            JPanel borderLayoutPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            borderLayoutPanel.add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(borderLayoutPanel);
            scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            add(scrollPane);


             Avvio();

    }
     private void Avvio() {

            JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                JButton button;
                pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;

                button = new JButton("Button 1");
                c.weightx = 0.5;
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 0;
                pane.add(button, c);

                button = new JButton("Button 2");
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 1;
                pane.add(button, c);

                button = new JButton("Button 3");
                c.gridx = 1;
                c.gridy = 1;
                pane.add(button, c);
            }

        }
```

Comment: `add(scrollPane);` add it to the `JFrame` instead of your `JPanel`

Comment: Sorry I do not understand

Comment: your class extends `JFrame`. therefore the method `add()` adds everything to the class (`JFrame`) and not to the `JPanel` as you want to